# Problema para conectar dos monitores

Tags: ubuntu

tengo Ububtu 22.04 LTS y la pantalla de mi portatil da fallos, así que he probado a instalar un segundo monitor (con hdmi). Este funciona y hace un duplicado de la pantalla de mi portatil. No he tenido que revisar las opciones de display, directamente funcionaba. Ahora, he intentado conectar otro monitor, para tener de nuevo mis dos pantallas funcionando, pero, al ir a conectarlo, y entrar a settings/Display, resulta que no tengo la opción de conectar un segundo monitor, y de hecho, parece como si no tuviera otro conectado, os enseño lo q me aparece.[image: Esta es mi pantalla de display]

¿Alguien sabe por qué me pasa esto?Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estimada este es un sitio de programación

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate que tu laptop soporta la visualizacion de 3 monitores al mismo tiempo (la pantalla de tu portatil y los dos monitores extra) el hecho de que tu portatil tenga varios puertos hdmi no significa que lo soporte, tambien intenta probando solamente con el monitor nuevo, ya descartando que sea algo del monitor nuevo, el problema radicara en la capacidad de tu tarjeta grafica para tener monitores simultaneos